# SQL: How to self-reference a column in update statements?

Tags: sql, sybase

I have two tables with these columns:

Users:
user, class, grade, location.

Classes:
class, location

The class column of the Users table references the same colmn in Classes table.

I want to update all rows in the Users table such that each row of the Users table's "location" column is equal to the location of the class.

So i have a row with values:
Mike, Math, A+, New York

And the corresponding row in Classes table for Math is:
Math, Chicago

I want the user table's row to become
Mike, Math, A+, Chicago.

Thanks

Comment: You might want to consider normalizing your data.  If the location is only dependent on the class, why store it in the user table as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update users a
    set a.location =
     (select b.location 
      from classes b
      where b.class = a.class)
```

Comment: I don't see where it is necessary.

Comment: Error handling isn't necessary either, but its good practice.

Comment: @Maess, you'll probably help your cause if you stated why a join would be better.

Answer (score 3):

```
update
  users
set
  users.location = classes.location
from
  classes
where
  classes.class = users.class
```

Comment: I don't believe this is valid syntax

Comment: Yes, it is valid syntax, at least in MS SQL Server, which I am pretty sure it similar enough to Sybase to apply here.

Comment: OK, did not downvote BTW, would the downvoter please supply a link to the docs specifying the error here? Meanwhile +1 to compensate.

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
UPDATE U 
SET U.Location = C.Location
FROM Users AS U
INNER JOIN Classes AS C ON C.Class = U.Class
                AND C.Location != U.Location
 ;
```

Comment: +1 for using a join.  Why do I keep seeing answers to SQL questions where the join is omitted in favor of a sub select?