# replace data in column B with data from column A timestamp Null

Tags: sql, sybase

I have a Sybase database that I am trying to replace the data from one column to another when the columns are data type timestamp and the column I am trying to move the data into has nulls that I am trying to replace.

```
date                             redemption_date
04-03-2010 09:21:14.462          04-03-2010 09:21:14.462
04-03-2010 09:21:14.462          (null)
04-03-2010 09:21:14.462          (null)
04-03-2010 09:21:14.462          04-03-2010 09:21:14.462
```

The result I would like is

```
date                             redemption_date
04-03-2010 09:21:14.462          04-03-2010 09:21:14.462
04-03-2010 09:21:14.462          04-03-2010 09:21:14.462
04-03-2010 09:21:14.462          04-03-2010 09:21:14.462
04-03-2010 09:21:14.462          04-03-2010 09:21:14.462
```

I have tried -

```
UPDATE accounts_receivable SET redemption_date = date
UPDATE table_name SET column_b = column_a
```

Thanks Jeff

Comment: you want a "where redemption_date is null", don't you?

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track. As [Paul Kienitz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2250981/paul-kienitz) said in his comment, you need to add a `WHERE` clause to filter which records you want to update. Try something like:

```
UPDATE accounts_receivable SET redemption_date = date WHERE redemption_date IS NULL;
```

This will copy the data from the `date` column to the `redemption_date` column wherever the `redemption_date` field is `(null)`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I get a syntax error near WHERE.

Comment: Can you be more specific about which error you are getting?

Comment: Error at line 1 Syntax error near 'Where'....This is sybase 6, I forgot to put the version when I asked the question.

Comment: If I " double quote everything it comes back 0 records updated

Comment: You shouldn't need to quote anything. Make sure that nothing is misspelled or out of place. The query I posted above should do exactly what you have described.

Comment: I have typed everything out and make sure the spelling is proper and its still giving the same syntax error near where. Any suggestions?

Comment: I am not sure what is wrong based on the information you have provided so far. It may be that you have to reference the table names as well, perhaps through joins. See the answers in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8217721/sql-how-to-self-reference-a-column-in-update-statements) for some possible solutions.